# add field to memmaped numpy record array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

With normal memmapped numpy arrays, you can "add" a new column by opening the memmap file with an additional column in the shape.

```py
k = np.memmap('input', dtype='int32', shape=(10, 2), mode='r+', order='F')
k[:] = 1

l = np.memmap('input', dtype='int32', shape=(10, 3), mode='r+', order='F')
print(k)
print(l)
```

```
[[1 1]
 [1 1]
 [1 1]
 [1 1]
 [1 1]
 [1 1]
 [1 1]
 [1 1]
 [1 1]
 [1 1]]
[[1 1 0]
 [1 1 0]
 [1 1 0]
 [1 1 0]
 [1 1 0]
 [1 1 0]
 [1 1 0]
 [1 1 0]
 [1 1 0]
 [1 1 0]]
```

Is it possible to make a similar move with record arrays? Seems possible with rows, but can't find a way to do so with a new field, if the dtype has heterogeneous types.

Comment: The `columns` of a `record` array, aka, a structured array, are defined by the `dtype`.  They are fields, not a dimension of the `shape`.  Read the docs: https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/user/basics.rec.html

Comment: thanks for the comment, I clarified the question.

Comment: In your example, because of the order 'F', 'columns' are the outermost dimension.  It appears that defining a new memmap is like doing `arr.resize`.  The new elements are filled with 0s.  Change the shape to (11,2) to see the difference.  A compound `dtype` is more like an inner most dimension; the field values of a record are contiguous.